# How to put a Google Analytics object in a $_SESSION variable between PHP scripts? (Non-object error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-analytics-api

I am building a web application using Google Analytics API, but I am running into some difficulties thinking of an implementation.

I am allowing the user to select their profile from three drop-down menus that are dependent on each other (think country->state->city). I am using AJAX to grab a value from the first drop-down (country), and I am trying to populate the second drop-down from Google Analytics API in an external PHP script.

I am trying to bring the Analytics object ($analytics) over to an external script via a $_SESSION variable from index.php, but I cannot call the $analytics functions I need to populate the second drop-down.

I var_dumped the variable, it initially told me it's an incomplete PHP class, so I serialized it and deserialized between the two classes. However, it still gives me:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function listManagementWebproperties() on a non-object
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this?

Just to clarify:

In **index.php**

```
        //create a session analytics object for use in external scripts
        $_SESSION['analytics'] = serialize($analytics;) //used for API calls
```

and the line in an external script throwing the error in my AJAX request, **propertyID.php**:

```
$analytics = unserialize($_SESSION['analytics']);
$webProperty = $analytics->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($accountID); //the array used to populate the drop-down
```

EDIT: Could this be an issue due to the API object?

Comment: How do you define `$analytics` in index.php?  `$analytics = new Something();`?  If so you need to include that class in propertyID.php.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);` and I included the same require_once lines I have in my index.php in my external script

Comment: I am not all that sure you can unsterilized the Google_Service_Analytics object like that.  Normally I just save the refresh token and make the request that way.  On a side note if all you are doing is building dropdowns for the user account information its easer to go though the Account summary report.  $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);  
// request user accounts
$accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

Comment: @DalmTo I see. I also didn't know about listManagementAccountSummaries(), what exactly does this return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround to my problem.

Instead of storing the `Google_Service_Analytics()` object in the session, you can store the `Google_Client()` object in the session instead. From there you can declare the `$analytics` object as you would normally:

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it could be related to some transient data that makes the class not serializable.

I think you have to create the Google objects in every page call and serialize in $_SESSION only the data useful to create these instances.

Comment: I assume this is the case as I have tried multiple approaches and serializing different function calls but all give the same result... I'm hoping for an easy solution otherwise I'm going have to use several AJAX requests to do what the method can do in a single line.

Comment: But, correct me if I'm wrong, in any case you would need n-request by AJAX to complete your form because you have to build it on top of successive query, isn't? So I'm missing what you're trying to achieve with one-shot request.